# Unir archivos PDF con marcadores

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo un código en asp.net en C# en el cual uno varios documentos PDF, cada PDF tiene marcadores y al momento de unir los archivos no me respeta los marcadores.

Con la librería ItextSharp manipulo los PDF para unirlos, pero como menciono antes no me respeta los marcadores de cada archivo.

Trate agregar los marcadores al unir el PDF de la siguiente manera:

```
Chapter chapter4 = new ChapterAutoNumber("Prueba___1");
chapter4.BookmarkTitle = "Bubble Drawing";
sourceDocument.Add(chapter4);
```

Agrega los marcadores, pero necesito que me respete los que ya tenia anteriormente los documentos antes de unirlos.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, ya edite la pregunta y espero que sea la manera correcta de narrar el problema que tengo.

Comment: Gracias Alexis por editar su pregunta. Si no lo ha visto, le recomiendo usar el código de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883360/4092887) para unir los PDF's. Tal vez con ese código se mantengan los marcadores.